# how can I apply multiply each as express handlebars (#each)?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

.Handlebars file

```
 {{#each products}}
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
              <div class="product_block">
                <div class="product-image-container image">
                  <a href="#" class="product_img_link">
                    <img src="{{**???**= /images/product-1-1.jpg}}" alt="product-1-1" class="img-product" />
                    <span class="product-additional">
                      <img src="{{**???**= /images/product-1-2.jpg}}" alt="product-1-2-back" />
                    </span>
                  </a>
```

.index.js

```
app.get('/collections/all', (req, res) => { res.render('collections/all', {
title: 'All Products',
products: [
  '/images/product-1-1.jpg',
  '/images/product-1-2.jpg',
  '/images/product-2-1.jpg',
  '/images/product-2-2.jpg'
] }); });
```

Q. As you can see, I want to apply like 'product-1-1' and 'product-1-2' each `<img>` 
But How can I apply each `<img>` as `{#each}` ???
Because I have to repeat `<div class="col->`.. 
So it is hard to apply ?

Excuse me, please help me ~

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to rearange your data. At least you will have the opportunities of the (dynamic) `each` loop instead of comparing (static) filenames.

```
products: [
  {
    front: '/images/product-1-1.jpg',
    back: '/images/product-1-2.jpg',
    altFront: 'product-1-1',
    altBack: 'product-1-1-back'
  },
  {
    front: '/images/product-2-1.jpg',
    back: '/images/product-2-2.jpg',
    alt: 'product-2-1',
    altBack: 'product-2-1-back'
  },
]

{{#products}}
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="product_block">
            <div class="product-image-container image">
                <a href="#" class="product_img_link">
                    <img src="{{front}}" alt="{{altFront}}" class="img-product" />
                    <span class="product-additional">
                        <img src="{{back}}" alt="{{altBack}}" class="img-product" />
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/products}}
```